# Multiple Strange Errors when Starting TF2 Dedicated Server

Tags: steam, technical-issues, team-fortress-2, hosting

Before I ask this question, note that I am referring to a *strange* error in the console when starting my server, not a *strange* kill tracking weapon in Team Fortress 2!

When I start my server, I get 2 strange sounding errors in the console. They both relate to, what I think is, missing textures. This does not affect the game play so far, but have not seen these errors on other servers. I say this is strange because I have followed the [official Team Fortress 2 Dedicated Server set up guide](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Windows_dedicated_server). I have taken screenshots of the two errors:

[image: Error one. Missing skybox textures?]
This is error one. A lot of missing skybox textures are detected which may effect some maps.

[image: Error two. Missing variables for some development materials?]
This is error two. This is the most interesting one because it seems to be missing the variable `$CO_X` which seems to be referring to a development texture.

------
Any help regarding fixes to these errors, or what these errors even are would be appreciated.
**Note: I have sv_pure set to 2 and SourceMod and MetaMod installed. No plugins are installed however. You can find my server.cfg on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4nzV41gi).**

EDIT: Later on I was on my server and I opened the terminal to this. I don't know what it is but seems like more missing textures?[image: More missing textures]

Answer (score 1):

Are these errors in the server console or the client console?  Because I'm not seeing errors like this in my server console.

As for the client console, as much as I hate to say it, a lot of errors like these can just be ignored.  This wouldn't be the first time Valve has materials that are missing values in their VMT files.

Alternately, you can validate the game's install files through Steam to make sure nothing is missing (you can validate server files as well by adding `validate` to the end of the `app_update` command).

Comment: This is in the client console. Don't even mention the errors in the server console! http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232504/team-fortress-2-dedicated-server-reports-all-maps-are-missing/