# Team Fortress 2 Dedicated Server Reports all Maps are Missing?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, hosting, server-administration

Recently, I installed MetaMod and SourceMod. Since I installed these I have been having the server report that it cannot find any maps. This is strange because when I go on the server as a client, everything seems fine. I have not installed any SourceMod plugins and have taken a picture of the errors here. Note it says a lot more that in the screenshot, but it is just saying the same thing for every map.
[image: Server error]

I also took a picture of my maps folder (`hlserver\tf2\tf\maps`) and the maps were all there:
[image: Map folder]

And here is my server running `ctf_2fort` with no problems!
[image: Server is running fine!]

I think this might actually be a bug in either SourceMod, MetaMod or `SteamCMD` for reporting it wrong because it clearly does have the maps, and can read them fine. However I do want to find a way to stop these errors.

*Also, if you are answering this question as an experienced Source game server administrator you may be interested with helping me with [this question here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232481/multiple-strange-errors-when-starting-tf2-dedicated-server) as my server is showing up strange errors before it even reports the missing maps.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually being caused by SourceMod.  It calls `Map_IsValid` internally.

However, Valve changed it so `Map_IsValid` now takes absolute paths.

Installing a [SourceMod 1.7.3 snapshot](http://www.sourcemod.net/snapshots.php) should fix this issue as it now uses the new `FindMap` command to resolve map names instead.

Comment: Thanks for this answer it works perfectly. For anyone else with this error here are some direct links to the fixed snapshot: Windows - http://www.sourcemod.net/smdrop/1.7/sourcemod-1.7.3-git5233-windows.zip Linux - http://www.sourcemod.net/smdrop/1.7/sourcemod-1.7.3-git5233-linux.tar.gz MacOs - http://www.sourcemod.net/smdrop/1.7/sourcemod-1.7.3-git5233-mac.zip

Comment: Actually, apparently I lied when I said it's absolute paths.  Instead, it's rooted at the application's main directory... so instead of taking `"cp_dustbowl"` as input, it needs `"maps/cp_dustbowl"`.  However, since the game now uses `FindMap` internally to resolve maps in a mapcycle file, SourceMod now uses it as well.  Which can resolve `"cp_dust"` to cp_dustbowl among other things.